# referencing table in document

Tags: tables

I have completed the following table below. However now I am trying to give the table a caption underneath, I just want to caption it Table 1: Variables. However when I try it I am running into problems, looking for some help thanks! I have included a screenshot

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
{\footnotesize
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{1.45cm}>{$}c<{$}Xlp{1.5cm}} \toprule
& \text{Symbol}
    & \hfil Description                   & Unit     & Constraint\\
\midrule
Variables
& S_H & Number of susceptible humans & number   & $S_H \geq 0 $ \\
& I_H & Number of infected humans & number   & $I_H \geq 0 $ \\
& R_H & Number of recovered humans & number   & $R_H \geq 0 $ \\
& V_H & Number of vaccinated humans & number& $ V_H \geq 0$ \\
& N_H & Number of total human population & number   & $N_H > 0 $ \\
& S_M & Number of susceptible mosquitoes & number   & $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
& E_M & Number of exposed mosquitoes & number   & $E_M \geq 0 $ \\
& I_M & Number of infected mosquitoes & number   & $I_M \geq 0 $ \\
& N_M & Number of total mosquito population & number   & $N_M > 0 $ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is very elementary question about `latex`. you should read some introduction text about `latex`. for floats see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions, and for table settings https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: as Zarko already said, you should really read something about LaTeX. I'd suggest [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf) or anything else from [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `table` environment and inside it the `\caption` command. To reference it later use `\label{...}` inside of `\caption` (make sure to not introduce spurious spaces here), and use `\ref{...}` to reference it (`\ref` will produce only the number). Referencing needs at least two LaTeX runs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{1.45cm}>{$}c<{$}Xlp{1.5cm}} \toprule
& \text{Symbol}
    & \hfil Description                   & Unit     & Constraint\\
\midrule
Variables
& S_H & Number of susceptible humans & number   & $S_H \geq 0 $ \\
& I_H & Number of infected humans & number   & $I_H \geq 0 $ \\
& R_H & Number of recovered humans & number   & $R_H \geq 0 $ \\
& V_H & Number of vaccinated humans & number& $ V_H \geq 0$ \\
& N_H & Number of total human population & number   & $N_H > 0 $ \\
& S_M & Number of susceptible mosquitoes & number   & $S_M \geq 0 $ \\
& E_M & Number of exposed mosquitoes & number   & $E_M \geq 0 $ \\
& I_M & Number of infected mosquitoes & number   & $I_M \geq 0 $ \\
& N_M & Number of total mosquito population & number   & $N_M > 0 $ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{A table\label{tab:tabel}}
\end{table}

If you want to reference it, use \ref{tab:tabel}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I seem to be getting some errors from your solution

Comment: @user123 then it seems you're doing something wrong. Please be more specific. What is the error message you get? Are you sure it is related to this answer? Did you try the above code on its own and still get an error?

Comment: i am getting a error from your \caption{A table... line.

Comment: @user123 Did you place everything inside a `table` environment and the `\caption` outside of `tabularx` but inside `table` (`tabularx` being inside the `table` environment, too)?

Comment: my error is saying the caption is outside the float

Comment: @user123 then you did not put the `table` environment around your `tabularx` and `\caption`. In the code above there is a `\begin{table}` ... `\end{table}` block around `tabularx` and `\caption`.

Comment: my mistake, i made a mistake when copying and pasting your code. Thanks!